# Insights for writing an Assembler

Tags: assembly

I have defined an instruction set which only have load, store, move, add and subtract operation. Now I want to write an assembler which will take a file containing the instructions I have defined and produce the executable code.

I know the theories of compiler constructions like scanning, parsing, intermediate code etc. I want to write it in C. I have gone through some links like `compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/` and several others.

I am stuck in some questions like how can I map my instruction to the instruction provided by underlying processor?, how can I produce executable code for x86 as well as 68000 etc. I have defined a very minimal instruction set and I want no optimization just for sake of simplicity. Can anyone help me with above questions and give me some insights as well?

Comment: This is a very open-ended question. Can you ask something more specific? You can download documentation on instruction sets from most chip manufacturers. ([Here's](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) Intel's, and [Here's](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf) Motorola's 68k reference.) In order to assemble your program, you need to translate your assembly instructions into the instructions for the destination chip (x86 or 68k, for example).

Comment: You really should put spaces between sentences. Makes it easier to read.

Comment: @CodyGray: that's what I was doing, till your edit broke my edit -.-

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an assembler, then you have far less work and complexity than a compiler. First place to look would be open-source assemblers, such as [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/download.php) or [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/?C=M;O=D), from these you can gleam how to do the code generation.

IMO, the best approach is to generate a intermediate representation or bytecode (which you can even mach a VM for if you are interested), then create a state structure to hold common data and generation function for each machine target. And because your instruction set is small, this should be pretty easy, all the generation could be done using a switch inside a loop.